# Inspector not Showing Scripts in Multiple Versions of Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, virtual-reality, inspector

I have recently started learning VR on udacity, and when I use unity, no scripts show up in the inspector. When I use 5.6.1p2, I get this message.

[image]

Here is the console tab

[image]

I recently installed a beta version of unity, as referred to by a mentor, and there is no longer an error message, but the scripts simply do not appear

Comment: The referenced script was not imported and isn't in the Assets directory. You need to import it too. Also, don't post error messages as screen shots, particularly the whole screen. Crop that section or type it out.

Comment: @Draco18s When I downloaded the assets, it was already loaded into the `scripts` folder. I'll make sure to type the section out next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved:

After putting course assets into a new folder, and extracting them, all dependencies were accessible within unity. Library was rebuilt with all required dependencies, and project is completed and working.

To open the project, I opened unity first, and used the open project button to select the folder including the `assets`, `library`, and `temp` folders. When I opened through the `assets` folder, the library wasn't complete, therefor not all components and dependencies were accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Unity not show folders with corrupted meta file. just delete meta file with this folder name